# DRUPAL: combine CCK image and videos in a common ordered list. Possible?

Tags: drupal

I'm working on multiple videos and images page on Drupal.

I would like to know if I can combine Video and Image CCK fields in back-end content type pages, in order to assign them a common mixed order, when I have multiple images and videos.

ps. I don't want to create a node for each image/video, I prefer to use the CCK fields, since it is easier for my customer to manage the files, change the order and delete them.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can set a generic field type, use filefield module, and in the 'allowed filetypes' setting enter all image and video filetypes (png jpg gif avi flv etc), then also set 'unlimited' for the quantity allowed.

That said, maybe you need to explain your question or situation further, maybe provide a more detailed use case. Everyone seems confused about your question, and your basic structural plan may be flawed.

Usually you want to keep these things in separate fields, then use different views to pull exactly what you want. View1 would pull videos from the video field of the content type, View2 would pull images from the image field of the content type, View3 would pull videos and images, etc. When they are all mixed into one field you have to do extra parsing on the end to get what you want out, and that's more difficult.

But I don't think we understand what you are asking, an example case may help us help you.

Comment: hi, I cannot do what you suggested because this is the error message I get when I "png" and "jpg" extensions to the "allowed filetypes": "Only web-standard videos are supported through the video widget. If needing to upload other types of files, change the widget to use a standard file upload." It simply doesn't work

Comment: About the Views. You can read my Ps. in my question: "ps. I don't want to create a node for each image/video, I prefer to use the CCK fields, since it is easier for my customer to manage the files, change the order and delete them." Furthermore, if my customer wants to delete a view or create a new one, all the referenced nodes are not automatically deleted, so this would be another problem. CCK fields work greats under this aspect.

Comment: So basically I will try to clarify the question: I want to merge the CCK Video and CCK Image fields into one, so that I can upload mixed content in one single list and displaying it correctly (flv player for flv files, and normal images for images). I'm afraid what I'm asking is impossible.

Comment: Yeah I think it is not possible with today's modules, if you know php you can try hacking that module to accept what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just asking if you can have image fields and video fields on the same content type, then the answer is yes.

That said, I have no idea what you mean by "a common mixed order."

Comment: thanks for reply. No, I didn't meant that. I already have image and video fields in the same content type, and they are 2 different fields indeed. I would like to somehow merge them into 1 field. This because, when I have multiple files, I would like to be able to order all elements merging the 2 lists. i.e. 1. Video 2. Image 3. Image 4. Video and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using Views. http://drupal.org/project/views

Set it up to display Nodes and then add in all the fields you want, you can then set the style to be Ordered List. This should give you something similar to what your trying to achieve.

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. Please check the "Ps." statement in my question. The reason for not using nodes is that the "Unlimited CCK Fields" is very use to use for my customers and also, when a page is deleted all the images/videos are deleted automatically.

So what am I asking is: "what I asked is not possible right ?"